# Place variable one context up in Eclipse JDT

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-jdt

I've been looking for the Eclipse JDT refactoring tool which allows me to quickly change

```
if (...) {
  Object x = blablabla;
}
```

to

```
Object x;
if (...) {
  x = blablabla;
}
// insert code using x here
```

But I can't find it. Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

But, you can use the "Split Variable Declaration" refactoring (CTRL+1 on the declaration gets you a list of possible refactoring options) and than relocate the declaration yourself using Cut/Paste or drag&drop.

Comment: Good enough, it so happens I was also looking for that option.

Comment: ...or alt-up arrow.  Or option-up arrow for Mac users.

Comment: I have been looking for this for a long time. I should raise a request with eclipse now :)